# On working around an essential singularity

Tags: complex-analysis

I have an integral expression that is divergent, but I'd like to try and add some convergence factors that might perhaps, induce convergence without upsetting the result I'm trying to get at. Where the result is divergent, how I've analyzed it, it is an essential singularity. By this I mean,

Our auxillary function is $$\vartheta(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$ where this function is entire and of exponential order relatively small. That is to mean $|\vartheta(x)| \le C e^{|x|^{\rho}}$ for small $\rho$.

The integral that is divergent that I want, is the mellin transform of $\vartheta$

$$\phi(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \frac{1}{n+z} + \int_1^\infty \vartheta(x) x^{z-1}\,dx$$

Where I've written out the mellin transform in an unusual form that applies to entire functions. And we generally have that $\int_1^\infty \vartheta(x)x^{z-1}\,dx$ is divergent, and for my $\vartheta$ it is as well.

So I thought of analyzing $$\Phi(w,z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-wx} \vartheta(x)x^{z-1}\,dx$$

Which is convergent in the right half plane for $w$ and $z$.  I was able to get another expression for this in all $w$, and woe is me, there is an essential singularity at zero.

The expression comes from fractional calculus and is:

$$\Phi(w,z) = \Gamma(z) \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\dbinom{z}{n} w^{z-n}$$

And by the decay on $a_n$ it converges. ($a_n$ goes to zero about as fast as the reciprocal of the Ackermann numbers.)

Now, my question has two parts because I have two ideas on how to conquer this.

By continuity on all of $\mathbb{R}^+$ we have that for all $\epsilon$ if $\delta$ is small enough $|\vartheta(x) - \vartheta(x+\delta)| < \epsilon$ therefore:

$$\int_1^\infty |\vartheta(x) - \vartheta(x+\delta)|x^{\Re(z)-1} \,dx \le \frac{\epsilon}{|\Re(z)|}$$

If $\Re(z) < 0$
And by this, we have a convergent expression for $\Re(z) < 0$ $$\int_1^\infty (\vartheta(x) - \vartheta(x+\delta))x^{z-1} \,dx$$

Is this true? I think with some rigour it might be possible, I'm not certain though.

Another idea I have is to "remove" the essential singularity by multiplying $\Phi(w,z) \psi(w,z) = \beta(w,z)$ and by some brute force calculus on the choice of $\psi$ $\beta(0,z)$ is the function I want. As in, I've removed the essential singularity by multiplying $\Phi$ by another essential singularity.

Unfortunately I can't quite explain what I am trying to do with $\vartheta$, I'm just trying to lay everything on the table to perhaps find an answer from someone elses eyes.